# Mesoscopic structures of fluids in equilibrium?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics

When fluids are subject to external perturbations or put in certain geometries, they always show arguably the most fascinating structures : Starting from the eddies and vortices in pipe flows at large Reynold numbers, vortices of flows past an obstacle, or the vortices in fluids confined between two rotation cylenders.

Yet, a fluid at rest is often thought of just as a completely structureless phase : Apart from very small-scale features such as the arrangement of nearest neighbors or solvation structures in liquids, it is just a random phase and the trajectory of a tagged particle from the fluid simply obeys the Brownian law, without any other features.

But what I somehow intuitively expect is that most of the above mentioned "non-equilibrium" structures appearing under well defined conditions are present in the resting "equilibrium" fluid. This means if were to look at the trajectory of some fluid particle I expect to see imprints of the coherent non-equilibrium structures in the equilibrium trajectory, and not just see a Brownian trajectory.

Can you somehow relate to this ?